# MySQL Delete Timing Out

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to delete 8,000 records.
I'm repeating this process over multiple tables.
But for one of the smaller tables the delete is timing out.

I was expecting the transaction to complete in a few seconds.
I tried extending the lock wait to 5min+.
I tried deleting a couple different ways, without success.
I tried adding a filter for null values, but that also didn't resolve the issue.

Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Any help would be appreciated.

```
USE data;
SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 3000;

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
DELETE a
FROM data.table AS a
JOIN tempTable AS b ON a.KP = b.KP
WHERE KP IS NOT NULL;

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
DELETE a.* FROM
data.table as a
WHERE KP  IN (
SELECT KP FROM tempTable
) and  KP IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Avoid using `WHERE column in (SELECT ...)`, MySQL implements it poorly.

Comment: Make sure you have an index on the `KP` column in both tables.

Comment: Why are you setting [`innodb_lock_wait_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout) so high? Perhaps you meant to increase [`wait_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) or ['interactive_timeout'](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout)? Please add the DDL for the two tables involved and the `EXPLAIN` output for your two queries.

Comment: Hi. The WHERE clause was added during troubleshooting. I included it to show what I've tried during testing. During CSV import to the temp table I remove any records missing a primary key, but there are old records in the main table that are missing KP info.

Comment: Thanks, the table was missing a primary key. I had to export the data, clear the table, set a primary key, then re-import with a CSV.